# Kendo Validation, How to Ensure That an End Date is Greater Than or Equal to Start Date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I have two input fields on a webpage for a Start Date and an End Date and I am using kendo validation to ensure they are formatted properly; and that the End Date is greater than or equal to the Start Date. I have used the `data-greaterdate-field` attribute to successfully ensure that the End Date is greater than the Start Date; but what I really need is to ensure that it is greater than or equal to the Start Date. The `data-greaterdate-field` attribute corresponds to

```
validationtype = greaterdate
```

Is there a validationtype for greater than or equal to?

Here is sample of the code:

```
<input id="startdate" name="Start Date">
<input id="enddate" name="End Date" data-greaterdate-field="Start Date" data-greaterdate-msg='End date should be after start date'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle this into rules section of Kendo Validator.

```
function initializeValidator(){          
return $('#FormElement').kendoValidator({  
    rules: {        
     greaterdate: function (input) {        
      if (input.is('[data-greaterdate-msg]') && input.val() != "") {                                            
            var date = kendo.parseDate(input.val()),
            otherDate = kendo.parseDate($("[name='" + input.data('greaterdateField') +  "']").val());        
    return otherDate == null || otherDate.getTime() <= date.getTime();        
  }        
  return true;        
}
```

Note: "<=" does the trick inside rule's section. I've used Kendo version 2016.1.412